# Elasticsearch - Is it possible to collapse first then aggregate data of a nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using Elasticsearch and I want to group our results by a specific field, returning top n documents per group. The document have a nested filed and I want to aggregate all the documents' nested field for each group.

## Example

I have 5 documents and each have a groupId and also a nested field peoples. I want group these documents by the groupId. And then for each group, I want to get top 2 people(some documents may contain same people).

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
      "groupId":{
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "id":{
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "name":{
        "type":"text"
      },
      "people":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
          "email":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "name": "docs1",
  "groupId": "1",
  "people":[{
    "email":"people1@test.com"
  }]
}

PUT test/_doc/2
{
  "name": "docs2",
  "groupId": "1",
  "people":[{
    "email":"people2.1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "email":"people2.2@test.com"
  }]
}

PUT test/_doc/3
{
  "name": "docs3",
  "groupId": "2",
  "people":[{
    "email":"people3.1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "email":"people2.2@test.com"
  }]
}

PUT test/_doc/4
{
  "name": "docs4",
  "groupId": "1",
  "people":[{
    "email":"people4.1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "email":"people4.2@test.com"
  }]
}

PUT test/_doc/5
{
  "name": "docs5",
  "groupId": "3",
  "people":[{
    "email":"people5.1@test.com"
  },
  {
    "email":"people5.2@test.com"
  }]
}
```

Search query

```
GET test/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "groupId",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name":"inner",
      "size": 2
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "groupId": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 2,
  "from": 0
}
```

Result

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 5,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "docs1",
          "groupId": "1",
          "people": [
            {
              "email": "people1@test.com"
            }
          ]
        },
        "fields": {
          "groupId": [
            "1"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "1"
        ],
        "inner_hits": {
          "inner": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 3,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "docs1",
                    "groupId": "1",
                    "people": [
                      {
                        "email": "people1@test.com"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "docs2",
                    "groupId": "1",
                    "people": [
                      {
                        "email": "people2.1@test.com"
                      },
                      {
                        "email": "people2.2@test.com"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "name": "docs3",
          "groupId": "2",
          "people": [
            {
              "email": "people3.1@test.com"
            },
            {
              "email": "people2.2@test.com"
            }
          ]
        },
        "fields": {
          "groupId": [
            "2"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "2"
        ],
        "inner_hits": {
          "inner": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "test",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "docs3",
                    "groupId": "2",
                    "people": [
                      {
                        "email": "people3.1@test.com"
                      },
                      {
                        "email": "people2.2@test.com"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expecting is to aggregate a groupPeople field for each group and it contains top n people of that group(should not affected by the inner_hit size, like for groupId=1, it contains 3 documents and 5 people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you're looking for is this one:

```
POST test/_search 
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "people": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "people"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "emails": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "people.email",
                "size": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need [pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination), you can achieve the same using the [`composite` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html):

```
POST test/_search 
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "pages": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "groups": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "groupId"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "people": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "people"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "emails": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "people.email",
                "size": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you val! An addition question, how can I do a pagination on the groupId term?(return paginated groups)

Comment: Hi Val, is there any limitation using composite aggregation? I used to hear about there is limitation on max-buckets size. Will it affects if I have 1M groups?

Comment: The composite aggregation has been created especially for that, i.e. to not get into the max-buckets limit, since you can paginate through all the buckets, however many there are: https://www.elastic.co/blog/composite-aggregations-elasticsearch-pizza-delivery-metrics

Comment: Hi Val, I am running into a problem when using composite aggregation. See the error message like below.
"reason": {
          "reason": "Index 129 out of bounds for length 129",
          "type": "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception"
        }
Looks like to many people caused this error. Do you have any idea to resolve this?
BTW, in my case, it could be thousands of people for one group.

Comment: @feng feel free to create a new thread description your issue

Comment: ok. I am starting a new question followed this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75659540/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception-happened-when-using-composite-aggregation