# array_index_out_of_bounds_exception happened when using composite aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Following up this question [Elasticsearch - Is it possible to collapse first then aggregate data of a nested field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458546/elasticsearch-is-it-possible-to-collapse-first-then-aggregate-data-of-a-nested). When there are to many groups and too many peoples, elastic search failed to aggregate people.
`"failures": [ { "node": "94vFxNrZQjakNB6fRClHUA", "index": "test", "reason": { "reason": "Index 129 out of bounds for length 129", "type": "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception" }, "shard": 3 } ]`

In my case, there could be thousands of groups and each group could contain more than one people.

Comment: You probably need to show your query as well

Answer (score 0):

Added sort in top_hits resolved the issue.